# Proper Redux usage general questions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im a little uncertain as to how Redux ties in with React ( without using the ReactRedux library ). Assume the following component structure

```
App
--TodoListController
----SomeComponent1
----TodoList
------TodoItem
--ProfileController
```

**Question 1. Which components should listen for changes?**:

Im assuming that the proper component to subscribe for state changes in the redux main (and only ) store should be the TodoListController and the ProfileController respectively ( essentially the non presentation components ).

Is this correct to assume or should all components listen to the state and render whatever is of interest to them? I essentially dont know which component should listen to state changes and am only guessing at this point

**Question 2. Handling network calls:**

I know this is to be examined per case but ill mention it anyway. Currently im handling network calls in the following manner:
A) When `TodoListController` mounts i get the state from the mainstore and also initiate a request to the server for the latest data. I also listen for changes in the store. So in practice:

```
class TodoListController extends React.Component{

componentWillMount(){
    mainStore.subscribe()
    getDataFromServer(function(data){
        mainStore.dispatch(data)
    })
}

getDataFromStoreAndUpdate(){
    this.state.datawecarefor = mainStore.todoReducer.data
    //set the state here to trigger a rerender
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    mainStore.unsubscribe()
}

render(){
 //render whatever component here that uses this.state.datawecarefor
}
}
```

Do you see any obvious flaws with this approach? I dont know what i dont know at this point.

**Question 3. Where should store related helper functions live?**

I currently have a reducer that holds all todolists for various users. Currently, when the redux store state updates i retrieve all this data and iterate through it to find the user im interested in. This shouldnt be in the controller itself but as a hepler function. I thought of creating a wrapper around the Redux store and it's reducers to create functions like `getTodoListForUser(userId)` but i dont know if thats the right approach. How do you handle logic like that?

*P.S: Many people will point out that i should use the ReactRedux library that comes with many optimisations and they re probably right. This however isnt a production project, only one im trying to put together to better udnerstanding the core of both these two libraries before moving to something more optimal.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you don't want to use ReactRedux, but luckily enough there is a video of Dan Abramov explaining the source code. You should watch it, it will explain why they did what they did and how they did it. When I was first learning how redux and react worked together it made every so much more clear (and then I used ReactRedux anyway :)).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJ38wSFbM3A

There has been a lot of debate on where to connect React App's to the redux store. But it's mostly recommended that you want to connect where it makes logical sense. For example, if you have a container component that holds a bunch of comments, you don't need to connect all of the comments, you can just connect the container. In the same light you don't just want to connect your entire app at the top because then its more expensive to diff and update your app.

On another note you should probably try to handle network calls in redux middleware and dispatch an action your react component catches to cause a render.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i ll take a look. 1) About the network calls. So you're saying i should use the redux store as a repository, request data from it and let it update itself by some logic that resides in there. In other words, that the components shouldnt know of how the data is given to them, only that its given to them by the store? 2) How about the helper functions i mentioned (question 3)? How do you usually approach this? Thanks a bunchload!

Comment: 1) The redux store should use the middleware to get and format the data and then it should dispatch an action that changes the state and if your react components are listening to this state change they will update. (Basically what you said, all the components know if they get data from the store)

Comment: 2) Check out https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html it explains how you can design your app state in such a way that it is easy to access without helper functions. The gist is that you create your state in a way that you can reference sections of it by id (kind of like a map/dictionary in other languages)

Comment: thanks, this is all very valuable information as im kinda studying this whole thing on my own. Tremendous help